# apply image effect (grayscale) to screen (pc monitor)

Tags: c#, c++, c, windows, image-effects

Is there any way to apply image effects like grayscale to PC screen programmatically (the language is not matter but if it be in `c#` is better)?

I mean for example when the code runs , pc-monitor shows everything in gray scale colors.

Any advice is acceptable.